# C- Using pointer on another type in structure when I need it in Interpret/ Compilator

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-search-tree, interpreter

we are writing a interpret of java language  (simplified a lot, its called IFJ16 language) as our team project.

The language we are coding is pure C (we cant use any OOP)

This is the problem:

In the interpret we need to read structures of type Instr

```
 typedef struct Instr {
     BTSNode *Id1; // Adress of first operand
     BTSNode *Id2; // Adresss of second operand
     BTSNode *Id3; // Adress where the result is added
     InstrType type; // Type of instruction. InstrType is enum struct (like insDiv, insMux, ...)
 }Instr;
```

BTSNode is a node in the binary tree where all variables (classes and function are storaged). The structure:

```
typedef struct tBTSNode {
        tableName key; // Key, variable/func,class name
        NodeType nodeType; // Type (class, func, var)
        union {
            struct tBTSNode *functions; // Pointer on functions of class
            int argNo; // Argument number if its function argument
    } tBTSNode;

        tabSymbol data; // Data
        int inc; // Was var initialized?

        struct tBTSNode *variables; // Pointer on function or class variables

        struct tBTSNode *lptr; // Pointer on left subtree
        struct tBTSNode *rptr; // Pointer on right subtree
    } BTSNode, *tBTSNodePtr;


    typedef struct tableSymbolVariable {
            varType type; //In var case: type of var | in function case= return var type | In class case: NULL
            varValue value; //In case of var: var value | In case of class and func: null
        } tabSymbol, *tabSymbolPtr;
    typedef enum {
        var_int,
        var_double,
        var_string,
        var_void,
    } varType;


    union {
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        char *stringValue;
    } varValue;
```

So Interprer got the **STACK OF INSTRUCTIONS** (its simple stack filled by Instructionf of type Instr), ordered (so first instruction will by executed first, ...). Interpret will by cycling while he execute last item of stack (In that time program ends).

So here is a problem. Where we have for example instruction

```
a = b + c;
```

Its quite simple. The structure will look like (note: thats not the real code, just for showing you whats the problem)

```
 typedef struct Instr {
     BTSNode *Id1 = adress of node with variable b
     BTSNode *Id2 = adress of node with variable c
     BTSNode *Id3 = adress of node with variable a (there will by the b+c result storaged)
     InstrType type = insPlus
 }Instr;
```

So I will just call my doMath function who got (of course I will check if the type are compt.)

```
Id3->data.value = Id1->data.value Id2->data.value;
```

So here is the problem. What if I change the example to this

```
a = b + 30;
```

What should I do? With the a and b there is no problem. I will just find there varibales in binary tree and add them into Id1 and Id3.
But **What should I do with the 30 number?**

I was thinking about changing Instr struction so Id1-Td3 will be void* pointers and in precedence analysis I will just retype them to BTSNode pointers (if they really are pointers) and the numbers (or string, ...) just retype on int* pointer in this case. So structure would be

```
     typedef struct Instr {
     BTSNode *Id1 = adress of node with variable b
     Int *Id2 = adress of node with variable c
     BTSNode *Id3 = adress of node with variable a (there will by the b+c result storaged)
     InstrType type = insPlus
 }Instr;
```

So **my question is:** Is this the "right" solution? Or I can do it better and MORE easily?

Thank you for your answers and help.

Comment: You already have different kinds of BTSNode, I think, so why not just make an additional "numeric constant" kind?

Comment: Yea I got that idea too. But there can be more types and our interpret types are almost done and we have no time for re-working :/

Comment: ... You're almost done with this and you don't have numeric constant support already?!

Comment: Yea. We forgott that when we were writing precedens and syntax an.... I know its bad but Thats why I'm asking for advice here. Is there any chance to "fix" that without any bigger re-write?

Comment: "we cant use any OOP" - Why not? C does not exclude using OOP. You should read a book about compiler/interpreter creation. A good one will details all this.

Comment: Olaf: Couse It's a school project and there are the these rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dummy anonymous variables with the constant values and refer to them from the instruction nodes like normal variables.